# Perl error: not a reference

Tags: perl, ubuntu, reference, storable

I recently migrated some Perl code from SunSolaris to a Linux(Ubuntu) box of 64 bit. After the migration `Storable.pm` is breaking with the following error:

```
Byte order is not compatible at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Storable.pm, at /home/VD/Cache.pm line 347.
```

After some research on the internet I found that I need to use `nfreeze` instead of `thaw`, but now I receive the following error:

```
not a reference at /home/VD/Cache.pm line 347.
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
    sub get
    {
      my($self, $type, $param_ref) = @_;
       #return 1 if(!$self->{'INI'}{'sf.system.cache.enabled'});

if($self->{'INI'}{'sf.system.cache.database.enabled'})
{
    ### DATABASE
    my $param = $self->SF::Cache::convert_parameter($type, $param_ref);

    if($self->SF::Cache::CACHE_TABLE_USERCONTENT && $$param{'type'} == 2)
    {
        ### user-content
        my $query = 'SELECT PARAM_CONTENT AS C, DATA AS D FROM    sf_cache_usercontent WHERE SITE=? AND PARAM_USER=?';
        my $bindvar = { 1=>$self->{'site'}, 2=>$$param{'user'} };
        my $sth = $self->db_select($query, $bindvar);
        #print SF::Util::debug_dumpquery($query, $bindvar);
        return undef if($self->{'Error'});

        my %usercontent;
        undef(%usercontent);
        while(my $hashref = $self->db_fetch($sth))
        {
            $usercontent{$$hashref{'C'}} = $$hashref{'D'};# ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return \%usercontent;
    }
    else
    ### ******************************************************************************************************
    {
        my $ret = $self->SF::Cache::get_database('DATA', $param);

        return Storable::nfreeze($ret) if(defined $ret);
    }
}
else
{
    ### FILESYSTEM
    my $filename = $self->SF::Cache::filename($type, $param_ref);
    if($filename && -e $filename)
    {
        if($self->{'INI'}{'sf.system.cache.lock.enabled'} && defined  &lock_retrieve)
        {
            return lock_retrieve $filename;
        }
        else
        {
            return retrieve $filename;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $! = 0;
    }
}
return undef;
}
```

Comment: Which line is home/VD/Cache.pm 347?

Comment: return Storable::nfreeze($ret) if(defined $ret);

Answer (score 1):

Go back to your original system, `thaw` then `nfreeze` the file there to fix it.

```
perl -MStorable=nstore,retrieve -e'nstore(retrieve($ARGV[0]), $ARGV[1])' file fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

So, "not a reference" means ... exactly what it says on the tin. Can you try printing the thingy with `Data::Dumper` from comments it's this line:

```
return Storable::nfreeze($ret) if(defined $ret)
```

So - what does:

```
print Dumper $ret;
```

produce? Is it a reference?

I'm not so sure though that you're right about needing `nfreeze` instead of `thaw`, because they both do different things. `freeze` packs a variable; `thaw` unpacks it. So `nfreeze` can replace `freeze`.

But the core purpose of doing this is to transfer your packed up scalar to another program on another architecture. Is this what you're doing?

If so, can I suggest instead considering transferring it as `JSON` or `XML` instead?

Comment: You are right about nfreeze an thaw, both are completely different. I need to leave line 347 in the original form:
return Storable::thaw($ret) if(defined $ret);
But this leaves me with my compatibility problem. Any suggestions how to fix  Byte order is not compatible at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Storable.pm, at /home/VD/Cache.pm line 347. ???